# CGI-PHP error and Redirection Issue Wordpress MU

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, cgi-bin

I installed wordpress Mu at http://www.optimalthinking.com/community/wp-admin/install.php

But when I visit http://www.optimalthinking.com/community/

I get

> Security Alert! The PHP CGI cannot be
>   accessed directly.
>
> This PHP CGI binary was compiled with
>   force-cgi-redirect enabled. This means
>   that a page will only be served up if
>   the REDIRECT_STATUS CGI variable is
>   set, e.g. via an Apache Action
>   directive.
>
> For more information as to why this
>   behaviour exists, see the manual page
>   for CGI security.
>
> For more information about changing
>   this behaviour or re-enabling this
>   webserver, consult the installation
>   file that came with this distribution,
>   or visit the manual page.

Can anyone tell me what's the problem and how it can be fixed.

Things I have tried so far:

1. Reinstalled the WPMU
2. http://mu.wordpress.org/forums/topic/5529
3. http://trac.mu.wordpress.org/ticket/502
4. Tried changing .htaccess

All these things didnt yield any results. If stackoverflow allows me, I would reward anybody who would fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You need to fix your **php.ini**

Add/fix this line:

```
force_cgi_redirect = 0
```

or, in latest PHP versions:

```
cgi.force_redirect = 0
```

[Thanks to FAQTS and Google](http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/16386/fid/51)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it have something to do with your configuration, for some reasons script trying to redirect user to cgi-bin folder which is private.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.php.net/security.cgi-bin

```
PHP CGI with VirtualHosts.

This is what I found out while trying to get php to work as CGI with Apache VirtualHosts.

By enabling 'force-cgiredirects', you *must*:
1) set 'cgi.fix_pathinfo=1' in php.ini
2) leave doc_root commented out (php.ini also)

If you miss item 1, the apache logs will show 'unexpected T_STRING' in the php binary.
If you miss item 2, you'll only see 'No input file specified.', instead of the expected output.

You can then turn on the php support for a particular vhost by defining:

Action php-script /cgi-bin/php

inside the corresponding <VirtualHost> directive.
```

Cheers.